# Symfony2 - Access control

Tags: access-control, symfony

I want to set `access_control` for everything, but not for the pattern `/login` (and maybe some more routes).

So I set up the path for login first, with the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.
Then I set up the path for everything, with the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`.

The problem is that login form is now generated twice. I see two login fields, two submit buttons, and so on.

If I remove the access_control rules I have no, and only set to one path like `/blog/.*` and with role: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`, it works fine, the login form is like it should be.

So my configuration of "*you need to be authenticated everywhere except here*" does not work.

This is what I tried to do when login form is generated twice:

```
access_control:
   - { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Does anyone have any good examples for how to set up such a rule?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I got the answer :) So if anyone should have this problem, you also have to let _wdt, and _profiler being accessed anonymously :)

```
 access_control:

       - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: +1 I ran into this issue today, couldn't figure out why it only happened in Firefox, but this fixed it!

Comment: I haven't checked so I'm not 100% but this problem will probably only occur when in dev mode.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add this firewall:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```